# Telekinetic and Telepathic, Terminology.

Tags: terminology

I've been looking through literature I can't find a word to describe someone who is telepathic and  has telekinesis. Someone who's telepathic is a Telepath, someone who has telekinesis is a telekinetic. But with so many literary characters displaying both abilities, I began to wonder, what do you call someone who exhibits both abilities?

Comment: *psychic* I'd say

Comment: Asking for generic terminology is off-topic on Writing. Your question doesn't seem to be about specific writing-related terminology, which is why I am voting to migrate this question to EnglishLanguage&Usage.SE

Comment: @Boondoggle "Psychic" suggests pre-cognative (predicting the future)…. a TV show I watched as a kid called various mental abilities "Psy-powers" or similar – like George Lucas coming up with the word Droid™. Use it in-universe, and use it a lot. Everyone will think it's a real word.

Comment: *Psychic* can also refer to extrasensory perception other than precognition, such as telepathy and telekinesis. "relating to or denoting *faculties or phenomena* that are apparently inexplicable by natural laws, especially involving *telepathy* or clairvoyance." (*Free Online Dictionary*)

Comment: How about "polytelec"?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of a word that is defined as the pairing of telekinesis and telepathy.

A [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/telepathy-vs-telekinesis-in-marvel-universe/49285#49285) from SciFi Stack Exchange (in reference to the Marvel universe) discusses characters who exhibit both abilities, but the abilities are referred to individually.

There is always the possibility that an author has coined a word for somebody who combines the two. For instance, Brandon Sanderson, in his [Mistborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistborn) series, made up words to describe characters who exhibited particular powers. He describes *crasher* as the name for somebody who is both a *coinshot* (somebody who can telekinetically push against metal) and a *skimmer* (somebody who can decrease their weight).

I have so far not encountered a term for somebody who is both a telekinetic and a telepath—but I would not be surprised if it exists somewhere. However, it's certainly not common enough to be universally known or even located with a quick search, let alone warrant an entry in a dictionary.

In general, I've heard terminology such as having "paired abilities"—or being "twinned" or "dual natured."

---

Note that various terms can be used to describe such "powers". Some include *psychic*, *psionic*, and *ESP*.

Another [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127858/difference-between-psionic-and-psychic-abilites) from SciFi Stack Exchange (also referencing Marvel) discusses the difference between *psychic* and *psionic*, and suggests that *psychic* is a more appropriate umbrella term.

Of course, Marvel is only one context for this, and many science fiction and fantasy books will handle it differently. (As will some real-world experimenters of extrasensory phenomena, who tend to use *ESP* more often.)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the abbreviation "TKTP" in science fiction, usually after first being introduced to the phrase "Telekinetic-Telepath" which it is short for.